# How fix this vertically centered bullets on a horizontal list?

Tags: css

I've being trying this for about 5 hours already, and I'm feeling really, really dummy. :s

The overall code is w3c validated.

The problematic snipped:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZnzYk/

- I've tried making the circle bullets with css using border radius;
- I've tried using a pseudo element.
- I've tried using sprites.

The bullet must be (more or less) on the vertical-middle of the text, cross browser, starting from IE8.

So I give up all methods and I'm trying with a background image.

**THE CSS:**

```
#main-navigation ul li {     
   display:inline; 
}

#main-navigation ul li a {     
   font-family: 'Miso', 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  
   display: inline-block;        /*seems to help on IE*/
   font-size: 1.25em;     
   margin-right: 6%;     
   text-align: right;     
   text-transform: uppercase;     
   background: url('http://s7.postimage.org/fvy10uk1j/bullet.png') no-repeat 100% 50%;  
   padding-right: 4%;     
   text-decoration: none; 
}   
#main-navigation ul li a:hover {     
   color: #ED1E79;     
   text-decoration: none;     
   background: url('http://s7.postimage.org/puiznbth3/bullet_Selected.png') no-repeat 100% 50%; 
}
```

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="main-navigation"> 
   <ul>         
       <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>         
       <li><a href="">and this is item 2</a></li>         
       <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>     
   </ul> 
</div>
```

I get everything but consistence. :( 
I don't mind if it stays more or less really, but all least, not that different as it is right now.

**Update:**

After Asif suggestion: 
adding padding-top to 3px has made them look more or less the same on IE 8, IE9 and good browsers. But it feels like a bit hacky and still not consistent (on IE the bullet it's more on top, on all others the bullet it's on bottom (due to the padding-top added);

**Isn't there a better CSS code to have the bullets vertically aligned with the text, that don't require a px by px adjustment ?**

The intended result:

[image: the intended result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should add some `padding-top:2px` (or `3px` too) into `#main-navigation ul li a`.

It works fine with my browser than, did not check it on all.

check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnzYk/1/

Hey i just got one more thing to you, I don't know it may help you.

[`vertical-align: middle`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Here you can [play with it](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=top) at w3schools.

Comment: It was a font-face problem. The bullets are INDEED aligned. The font text itself, isn't. :/ Having a padding has making this look a little better. The only solution being, that of changing the font family choice. I will accept your answer as appropriate. Cheers.

Comment: since this issue seems to be related with the font-face generation, no vertical-align will help here. The padding did, so, I rest my case. ;) Cheers.